# Taking the output from Google Place Autocomplete and referring back to it later

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I would like to take the Google API "Place Autocomplete" widget and take the output and apply it somewhere else. The widget in speak of is this one:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

The whole idea that I have is that I would like to get the property address from a Real Estate Agent on my website and as they type it in, have this API auto-complete it and then show them the google maps view of their property, then they would confirm that it is correct. What I am trying to figure out is how I can take the output of the API, the Auto-completed address, and then store that in a form that they can view at the end of the session that they began. The plan is to have an interactive way for them to put in their information, then it gets delivered to me on a straight from so that I can then help them with the service I provide. This is just the basics that I am trying to figure out. Later I would like to take the address and then search it on a site like "Zillow" and then have it return the square-footage and other basic information so that it can automatically recommend different packages for them.

I know that this seems like a lot but any information is good information. I won't stop doing research until I figure it out, but all help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You want to listen to the `place_changed` event, which occurs when (and only when) the user selects a suggested place (via click, or keyboard select).

Here I am using the `formatted_address` but check the `place` object as it contains more than just the formatted address.

```js
function initialize() {

    var ac = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
        types: ['geocode']
    });
    
    ac.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    
     // Get the place
     var place = ac.getPlace();
      
        // Insert formatted address
        document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = place.formatted_address;
    });
}
```

```css
body,html {
    font-family: Arial;
}

#autocomplete {
    width: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initialize"
        async defer></script>
        
<input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text"></input>
<div id="address">

</div>
```